# ec2-user does not has permission to write to web folder

Tags: linux, unix, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created an apache web server using CFT; this is using RHEL 7. In order to allow ec2-user to modify files in apache document root folder, I added the following in CFT (taken from var/log/cloud-init.log)

```
Jun 30 16:11:15 ip-10-205-0-135 cloud-init: groupadd www Jun 30 16:11:16 ip-10-205-0-135 cloud-init: usermod -a -G www ec2-user Jun 30 16:11:16 ip-10-205-0-135 cloud-init: chown -R root:www /var/www Jun 30 16:11:16 ip-10-205-0-135 cloud-init: chmod 2775 /var/www Jun 30 16:11:16 ip-10-205-0-135 cloud-init: find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \; Jun 30 16:11:16 ip-10-205-0-135 cloud-init: find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} \;
```

As you can see from log, this went fine. However, when logged under ec2, it gives permission error as below:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-206-32-92 html]$ aws s3 sync s3://gfrepo/releases releases download failed: s3://gfrepo/releases/binaries.html to releases/binaries.html [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'/var/www/html/releases/binaries.html' download failed: s3://gfrepo/releases/B1556013/B1556013.jar to releases/B1556013/B1556013.jar Could not create directory /var/www/html/releases/B1556013: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/html/releases/B1556013'
```

I ended up elevating my permission as sudo to complete s3 sync. Not sure why it's giving permission error for ec2-user. Here are the listing of the permissions:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-206-32-92 www]$ ls -l total 0 
drwxrwsr-x. 2 root www 6 Mar 21 02:33 cgi-bin 
drwxrwsr-x. 3 root www 55 Jun 30 16:11 html 

[ec2-user@ip-10-206-32-92 www]$ groups ec2-user 
ec2-user : ec2-user adm wheel systemd-journal www
```

As you can see ec2-user is part of www group and www is the owner of html sub-dir

Comment: For ec2-user to be able to write to document root it needs to be member of group www-data

Comment: It is; [ec2-user@ip-10-206-32-92 html]$ groups ec2-user
ec2-user : ec2-user adm wheel systemd-journal www

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure the `ec2-user` belongs to the group that has write permission

if the directory `/var/www/html` is owned by root it will not let you write to the folder.

first do you an `ls -l` on `/var/www/html`

find out what's the group name, it's next to user

then issue this command

```
sudo usermod -a -G www ec2-user
```

You need to add `ec2-user` to the `www` group

You're logged in `ec2-user`, although you're issuing an `aws s3 sync` command, you need permission to write to the permissible directory, that's why it's failing.

This directory `/var/www/html/releases/` does not have the permission.

```
Could not create directory /var/www/html/releases/B1556013 <----
```

or su to root and try the command.

Comment: I already have usermod -a -G www ec2-user in my CFT (I have attached the log above). Hence, when I type groups ec2-user, it shows that ec2-user is already part of www group {[ec2-user@ip-10-206-32-92 html]$ groups ec2-user
ec2-user : ec2-user adm wheel systemd-journal www}. Also, when I did ls -l against html folder, it shows www group {[ec2-user@ip-10-206-32-92 html]$ ls -l
total 12
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root www  258 Jun 30 15:06 error.html
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root www  334 Jun 30 15:06 index.html
drwxr-sr-x. 13 root www 4096 Jul 18 14:28 releases }

Comment: you're issue is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700921/s3-moving-files-between-buckets-on-different-accounts/17162973#17162973

Comment: you need to permit s3 command for source and destination. in your s3 setup, when you included the user in the config make sure that user has permissions to write to the directories, especially when creating files.

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's an unix issue. Pls see below, when I try to create folder or, file in html sub-dir under ec2-user, it gives permission error-[ec2-user@ip-10-206-32-92 releases]$ mkdir testfolder
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘testfolder’: Permission denied | [ec2-user@ip-10-206-32-92 releases]$ nano testfile Error writing testfile: Permission denied ]

Comment: ahh, no problem. make sure that user has permissions.