# aws s3 sync vs rclone vs something else?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, rsync, rclone

I need upload my incremental backups `~250 tb` to my aws s3 bucket.

- Average file weight ~ `1 gb`
- Also a lot of files ~ `30 mb`

#### Which tool is better to use for this task?

Comment: Why not just use the AWS CLI's `aws s3 sync` ?

Comment: AWS CLI is pretty tool for me. But I would like to receive substantiated reasons.

Comment: afaik aws cli doesn't let you sync buckets with 2 different sets of credentials. but rclone does see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69517798/3140992

Answer (score 0):

You can use S3CMD to copy data to S3 from local machine or any Server with terminal access

On Ubuntu

```
$ sudo apt-get install s3cmd
```

Install Latest s3cmd using Source

```
$ wget https://sourceforge.net/projects/s3tools/files/s3cmd/2.2.0/s3cmd-2.2.0.tar.gz

$ tar xzf s3cmd-2.2.0.tar.gz
```

To install s3cmd

```
$ cd s3cmd-2.2.0 
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

configure s3cmd using the Accesskey and Secret key Generated from AWS Credentials

```
$ s3cmd --configure
```

List complete  S3 Bucket

```
$ s3cmd ls
```

Creating a S3 Bucket

```
$ s3cmd mb s3://bucket_name
```

Upload a file in to Bucket

```
$ s3cmd put file.txt s3://bucket_name/
```

Upload a complete directory in S3 Bucket

```
$ s3cmd put -r backups s3://bucket_name/
```

Upload a complete directory in a S3 Bucket containing Folder

```
$ s3cmd put -r backups s3://bucket_name/folder_name/
```

Automatically Upload Backups in s3 using cronjob

Create a Cronjob

```
$ crontab -e
```

add below cmd and save the file

```
0 1 * * * s3cmd put -r backups s3://bucket_name/folder_name/backups_$(date +"%F %T")
```