# how to copy s3 object from one bucket to another using python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to copy a file from one s3 bucket to another. I get the following error:

> s3.meta.client.copy(source,dest)
>   TypeError: copy() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)

I'am unable to find a solution by reading the docs. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
source= { 'Bucket' : 'bucketname1','Key':'objectname'}
dest ={ 'Bucket' : 'Bucketname2','Key':'backupfile'}
s3.meta.client.copy(source,dest)
```

Comment: This answer works https://stackoverflow.com/a/68849632/3177007

Answer (score 135, accepted):

You can try:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
      'Bucket': 'mybucket',
      'Key': 'mykey'
    }
bucket = s3.Bucket('otherbucket')
bucket.copy(copy_source, 'otherkey')
```

or

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'mybucket',
    'Key': 'mykey'
 }
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'otherbucket', 'otherkey')
```

**Note the difference in the parameters**

Comment: How does this change when the source bucket is a public s3 bucket not under my account?

Comment: @geominded Check this out: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/copy-s3-objects-account/

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is it just me or is this an extremely weird function? Source is a dictionary but destination is two strings? WTH AWS? And of course the key names are capitalized just to make absolute sure they don't abide by any convention...

Comment: @foobarbecue Yup it is not the best way to go about it. Haven't checked the recent revision. Probably it will be fixed. If not can create an issue in their repo.

Answer (score 12):

Since you are using s3 service resource, why not use its own [`copy` method](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.copy) all the way?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
source= { 'Bucket' : 'bucketname1', 'Key': 'objectname'}
dest = s3.Bucket('Bucketname2')
dest.copy(source, 'backupfile')
```

Comment: `copy() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Key' `

Answer (score 9):

This is the syntax from [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy):

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
copy_source = {
    'Bucket': 'mybucket',
    'Key': 'mykey'
}
s3.meta.client.copy(copy_source, 'otherbucket', 'otherkey')
```