# Boto3 Amazon s3 copy object between buckets and capture response of destinatio

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, copy

I am copying objects between two s3 buckets. As a part copy process i am renaming the file, is there a way to capture the Object "key" response from destination after a copy succeeds

Reference:[how to copy s3 object from one bucket to another using python boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47468148/how-to-copy-s3-object-from-one-bucket-to-another-using-python-boto3)

s3_resource.meta.client.copy(copy_source, destination_bucket, modified_filename)

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I know of doing this is to make a call to list the objects in the target bucket and make sure that your file modified_filename is in the keys. Something like this should work (assuming you have only one profile in your ~/.aws/config or ~/.aws/credentials file:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

for obj in s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=destination_bucket)['Contents']:
    if modified_filename in obj['Key']:
        successful_copy = True
```