# How to copy a folder into another folder using minio python sdk?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, sdk, minio

Below is the code I'm trying.

```
from minio.commonconfig import REPLACE, CopySource

# copy an object `src` from a bucket `darshan` to object `dest_obj`
result = client.copy_object(
    "darshan",
    "dest_obj",
    CopySource("darshan", "src"),
)
print(result.object_name, result.version_id)
```

Errors:

1. I have to specify the source object as `src/` if I specify `src` below error:

`S3Error: S3 operation failed; code: NoSuchKey, message: Object does not exist, resource: /darshan/src, request_id: 16682AB6445C2722, host_id: None, bucket_name: darshan, object_name: src`

2. Similarly, I have to specify the destination object as `dest_obj/` else it creates a file instead of copied folder.
3. After specifying src & dest object in this manner, it creates an empty directory `dest_obj`. Not copying any contents from `src`

Comment: This might be the issue "host_id: None" I don't see you connecting to a client in the code

Comment: No issues with client creation. As I mention, in points 2, 3 its creating a directory but not what I expected.

Comment: I just thought it looked odd and might be worth pointing out.

did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47468148/how-to-copy-s3-object-from-one-bucket-to-another-using-python-boto3