# Run bash-command via subprocess in python without bandit Warning B404 and B603

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, bandit-python

Since the [pre-commit hook](https://pre-commit.com/) does not allow even warnings and commits issued by [bandit](https://github.com/PyCQA/bandit), I need to find a way to execute bash commands from python scripts without bandit complaining.

[image: bandit-lintings]

Using the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) python package, bandit has always complained so far, no matter what I did. I used ".run()", ".check_call()", ".Popen()", .. all without `shell=True` and yet there's no avail.

If there is a secure alternative to subprocess, I'd also be interested, but I'm sure it must work somehow with subprocess as well.

---

**Example** which is not accepted by bandit:

```
import shlex
import subprocess

...

bash_command = (
    f'aws s3 cp {source_dir} s3://{target_bucket_name} --recursive'
    f' --profile {profile_name}')
subprocess.check_call(shlex.split(bash_command), text=True)
```

Comment: Note: Instead of starting a `aws` CLI subprocess causing the bandit warning, you could instead use the (boto3 python library)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/47468350/771768] to do the same S3 Copy operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the code to be secure, you need to know that `source_dir` `target_bucket_name` `profile_name` aren't malicious: e.g. can an untrusted user pass `.ssh` as the value to be copied?

Once you know the subprocess line is secure, you can add `# nosec` comment to tell bandit not to give a warning about the line:

```py
subprocess.check_call(shlex.split(bash_command), text=True)  # nosec
```

---

(The command `aws s3 ...` running in `subprocess.check_call` isn't running in a bash shell, which might confuse people reading the question. Python will directly start the `aws` process, passing arguments.)

Comment: Okay, so there is no better way. Just evaluate for oneself, if the input arguments are secure, then add the `# nosec` - comment to silence the warning?

Comment: @AndreasL. Exactly, starting a subprocess is inherently risky, do you need to tell bandit you checked the args are safe.