# How can I transfer two objects from a bucket account1 to bucket another2?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I've been trying to transfer the objects from one bucket of an account1 to another bucket of
an account2.

I'm trying to:

```
source_bucket = s3.Bucket('source-bucket')
destination_bucket = s3.Bucket('destination-bucket')
destination_keys = [object.key for object in destination_bucket.objects.all()]
for object in source_bucket.objects.all():
  if (object.key not in destination_keys):
    # copy object.key to destination
```

How can I make the copy?

Comment: Hi :) Does this answer your question? https://www.stackvidhya.com/copy-move-files-between-buckets-using-boto3/

Comment: Or this, from this website: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47468148/how-to-copy-s3-object-from-one-bucket-to-another-using-python-boto3

Comment: Are you running this code using credentials from the 'source' or 'destination' AWS account? Are you successfully able to list objects in both buckets? If so, then it is likely that your permissions are setup correctly. It would just be a matter of creating the object. You can do this with the [`copy()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.copy) method.