# Recursively copy s3 objects from one s3 prefix to another in airflow

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow, boto3, airflow-2.x

I am trying to copy files that I receive hourly into my incoming bucket with the below format

```
s3://input-bucket/source_system1/prod/2022-09-27-00/input_folder/filename1.csv
s3://input-bucket/source_system1/prod/2022-09-27-00/input_folder/filename2.csv
s3://input-bucket/source_system1/prod/2022-09-27-01/input_folder/filename3.csv
s3://input-bucket/source_system1/prod/2022-09-27-11/input_folder/filename3.csv
```

I want to copy the objects into a destination folder with a single airflow task for a specific source system.
I tried -

```
   s3_copy = S3CopyObjectOperator(
                task_id=f"copy_s3_objects_{TC_ENV.lower()}",
                source_bucket_key="s3://input-bucket/source_system1/prod/2022-09-27-*",
                dest_bucket_name="destination-bucket",
                dest_bucket_key=f"producers/prod/event_type=source_system/execution_date={EXECUTION_DATE}",
                aws_conn_id=None
                )
```

The problem with the above is, I am not able to use `wildcards` for the input source_bucket. It needs to be a specific complete prefix of the s3 object. I also tried using the combination of `S3ListOperator` and `S3FileTransformOperator`. But all of them created a single task for each object. But I need 1 airflow task for 1 source system thus able to copy all the data with this wildcard pattern-

```
s3://input-bucket/source_system1/prod/2022-09-27-*
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Looks like I must use boto3 to achieve this. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249069/listing-contents-of-a-bucket-with-boto3

Comment: did you find a solution to this using native airflow operators? I can create a script but I am surprised there is nothing available within airflow that can do this

Comment: @eljusticiero67 I was unable to do it with a readily available airflow operator. But did a logic that iterates through the folder one by one from a list and then copy all files using the boto3 paginator logic. Similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47468148/how-to-copy-s3-object-from-one-bucket-to-another-using-python-boto3

Comment: thanks! i was able to use that and add that into a `PythonOperator`

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to achieve this in one specific task I recommend utilizing the PythonOperator to interact with the S3Hook as follows:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import Variable
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook
from datetime import datetime

def s3_copy(**kwargs):
    hook = S3Hook(aws_conn_id='aws_default')
    source_bucket = Variable.get('source_bucket')
    keys = hook.list_keys(bucket_name=source_bucket, prefix='')
    for key in keys:
        hook.copy_object(
            source_bucket_name=source_bucket,
            dest_bucket_name=Variable.get('dest_bucket'),
            source_bucket_key=key,
            dest_bucket_key=key,
            acl_policy='bucket-owner-full-control'
        )
    pass

with DAG('example_dag',
        schedule_interval='0 1 * * *',
        start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
        catchup=False
    ):

    e0 = EmptyOperator(task_id='start')

    t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id='example_copy',
        python_callable=s3_copy
    )

    e0 >> t1
```

You could make improvements on the base logic to be more performant or do some filtering, etc