# how to copy s3 object from one bucket to another using python s3fs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-s3fs

Using [python s3fs](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), how do you copy an object from one s3 bucket to another? I have found [answers using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47468148/how-to-copy-s3-object-from-one-bucket-to-another-using-python-boto3), but could not find anything when looking through the s3fs docs.

Comment: you definitely should probably use boto3 for this.

Comment: Is there a reason why this should be done with boto3 instead of s3fs?

Comment: nevermind, I think you just want `SFFileSystem.copy`

Answer (score 0):

Open from one bucket and write to another:

```py
s3 = S3FileSystem(...)

# You'll want to set a block size
# if your files are particularly large
block_size = 2**20

with s3.open('bucket_a/file', 'rb', block_size=block_size) as infile, s3.open('bucket_b/file', 'wb') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line)
```