# AWS S3 Download and Upload using TemporaryFile

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to download all content (including versions) of an Amazon S3 Bucket and upload in other Amazon S3 Bucket. Don't tell me to use aws, I just can't use.

I use tempfile.TemporaryFile for this, it apparently works, the print show that the file object has the right content inside, but the **uploaded** files are empty (zero bytes).

```
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as data:
    sourceUser.download_fileobj('source-bucket',key,data)
    # next 2 lines was just to check the content of the file
    data.seek(0)
    print (data.read())
    destinationUser.upload_fileobj(data,'destination-bucket',key)
```

Comment: Re-seek to offset 0 immediately before the upload? Or open a new stream on the file?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30161700/6779307)?

Comment: @Patrick - I can't use the aws/aws cli/boto3 direct copy from one bucket to other. I just can't in my project :(. So I have to do the download and upload model :(.

Comment: @ClaudiuIvanescu you don't have to use any library to do a direct copy from one bucket to another.  You can build and sign a request and send it to S3 using nothing but an hmac-sha-256 library and an HTTP user-agent... or a Lambda function behind API Gateway.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I'm sorry but I don't have enough knowledge for doing your way. jarmod showed the error and now works. But I don't want to take his credit!

Comment: This also sorted out a problem I was having, where I need to download and reupload (CV2 operations in my case need to happen). tmp.seek(0) also sorted my problem here. Thanks @jarmod

Answer (score 1):

I have the same requirement, How do I pass the NamedTemporaryFile to the upload s3

Not sure How to pass the NamedTemporaryFileName to output=f'{file_name}.gpg' and to the load_file function --> filename=f_source.name

```
with tempFile.NamedTemporaryFile("wb") as f_source:
                s3_client.download_fileobj(s3_bucket, s3_key, f_source)
                logger.info(f'{s3_key} file downloaded successfully to local {f_source}')
                f_source.flush()
                file_name = self.s3_key.split('/')[-1]
                gpg = gnupg.GPG()
                key_data = open(key_path).read()
                import_result = gpg.import_keys(key_data)
                f_source.seek(0)
                with open(f_source.name, 'r+b') as f:
                    status = gpg.encrypt_file(
                        file=f,
                        recipients=[recipient],
                        output=f'{file_name}.gpg',
                    )

                    s3_hook.load_file(
                        filename=f_source.name,
                        key=s3_key,
                        bucket_name=s3_bucket,
                        replace=True
                    )
```

Comment: You don't have a name for temporary file.... you have the data content as f_source. Don't try to reopen. Do seek 0 and save as you like.