# How to proxy a file with Python between two URLs

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

I'm working on a legacy code at work. We are storing our files in `AWS S3`. What I need to do is to move files from one S3 bucket to another(the one that our new application uses). There is a lot of stuff going one when one uploads a file to our application, so I decided the easiest way would be to emulate user uploading files to a new endpoint.

Now, how do I actually get a file from URL as a file object and then proxy it to another endpoint? Also, is there a way to do this without downloading file first? Im concerned about bigger files like videos.

What I've done so far is this:

```
url= 'https://example.s3.com/image'
file =  urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ssl._create_unverified_context())

payload = {'file': open(file, 'rb')}
data = {'title': 'Picture title'}
requests.post(final_url, files=payload, data=data, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

The error I get is this:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 590, in http_error_default
worker_1   |     raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
worker_1   | OSError
```

Now, I'm assuming that this is because `urllib` has nowhere to put file, even temporary.

How to fix this, and what would be a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Boto is likely your best option assuming you are able to directly access the buckets. This answer is an excellent reference. [How to move files between two Amazon S3 Buckets using boto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161700/how-to-move-files-between-two-amazon-s3-buckets-using-boto)

Comment: thanks @BryceH but I cant just upload to S3. We're doing some custom stuff with files before uploading them, so we really need to proxy them through our app.