# AWS S3 bucket - Moving all xmls files form one S3 bucker to Another S3 bucker using Python lamda

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, awss3transfermanager

In my case, I wanted to read all XML form my s3bucket/ parsing then move all parsed files to the same s3Bucker/

for me parsing logic is working fine but I am not able to move all files.
this is the example I am trying to use

```
**s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
src_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket1')
dest_bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket2')
for obj in src_bucket.objects.all():
    filename= obj.key.split('/')[-1]
    dest_bucket.put_object(Key='sample/' + filename, Body=obj.get()["Body"].read())**
```

above code is not working for me at all (I have to give s3 folder full access and for testing given public full access as well).

Thanks

Comment: If it's only a one time thing you could use the aws-cli instead of lamdba by using the 'aws s3 sync' command

Comment: NO my whole parsing logic is inside lamda and it will trigger once xml updated in IN folder and parse and move the parsed file to OUT folder.
And this is not one-time thing, this will for every time and bouk operation based on the Trigger event.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161700/move-files-between-two-aws-s3-buckets-using-boto3) You could use python `endshwith()` function and pass ".xml" to it, get a list of those files and copy them to the destination bucket and then delete them from the source bucket.