# How to copy from one bucket to another bucket in s3 of certain suffix

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have 3 buckets `1.commonfolder 2.jsonfolder 3.csvfolder`.

- Common folder will be having both json and csv files
- need to copy all csv files to csvfolder
- need to copy all json files to json folder

Code is below to get all the files from `commonfolder` How to copy after that

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #List all the bucket names
    response = s3.list_buckets()
    for bucket in response['Buckets']:
        print (bucket)
        print(f'{bucket["Name"]}')
        #Get the files of particular bucket
        if bucket["Name"] == 'tests3json':
         
            resp = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket='commonfolder')
            for obj in resp['Contents']:
                files = obj['Key']
                print(files)

            if(filename.split('.')[1].lower()=='json'):
                copyjson(bucket,filename)
                #copyjson(jsonfolder,filename)
            elif(filename.split('.')[1].lower()=='csv'):
                copycsv(bucket, filename)
                #copycsv(csvfolder,filename)
```

- need to create a new function copyjson,copycsv to do this job
- Need to copy from common-bucket to either csv-bucket or json-bucket depending on the file extension

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move files between two AWS S3 buckets using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30161700/move-files-between-two-aws-s3-buckets-using-boto3)

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing... You mention 3 buckets, but then your code runs on a bucket called `tests3json`, but then it lists objects in a bucket called `commonfolder`. Is your requirement to copy from `common-bucket` to either `csv-bucket` or `json-bucket` depending on the file extension? How will this Lambda function be triggered (eg manually, on a schedule, or when a file is uploaded to S3)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein,  Is your requirement to copy from common-bucket to either csv-bucket or json-bucket depending on the file extension?  yes

Comment: How will this Lambda function be triggered (eg manually, on a schedule, or when a file is uploaded to S3)? Should it only copy the file that caused the Lambda function to be triggered, or should it copy _all_ files in `common-bucket`? Please explain the workflow.

Comment: It has to trigger the lambda by  ` Add trigger `, only when file is uploaded in s3 then lambda  will triggered and copy the files from common-bucket to extension bucket

Comment: Are non-bucket answers okay with you?

Comment: @AnnZen, i am new to aws, what is non-bucket

Comment: Moving files from one directory to another without the use buckets.

Comment: @AnnZen Yes that is fine,

Comment: Let me know if my answer is not what you're looking for, so I can do further research.

Comment: All the buckets are in same account?

Comment: @Marcin, yes all are in same account

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the following code:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    source_bucket = s3.Bucket('01-commonfolder-231')
    json_bucket = s3.Bucket('02-jsonfolder-3435')
    csv_bucket = s3.Bucket('03-csvfolder-4552')
    
    for object in source_bucket.objects.all():
        
        #print(object)
        
        if object.key.endswith('.json'):
            
            print(f"{object.key} to json bucket")
      
            copy_object = json_bucket.Object(object.key)
            copy_object.copy({'Bucket': object.bucket_name,
                              'Key': object.key})                             
            
        elif object.key.endswith('.csv'):
            
            print(f"{object.key} to csv bucket")            

            copy_object = csv_bucket.Object(object.key)
            copy_object.copy({'Bucket': object.bucket_name,
                              'Key': object.key})
```

I tested this using my own sample buckets with test files:

```
aaa.json to json bucket
bbbbb.csv to csv bucket
bbbbb.json to json bucket
hhhh.csv to csv bucket
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `move()` method from `shutil`:

```
from shutil import move
from glob import glob

common_folder = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\commonfolder\\'
csv_folder = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\csvfolder\\'
json_folder = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\jsonfolder\\'

for csv in glob(common_folder+"*.csv"):
    move(csv, csv_folder)

for json in glob(common_folder+"*.json"):
    move(json, json_folder)
```